# Como obter informações do IIS via c#?

Tags: c#, iis

Como fazer para obter em c# algumas informações do IIS como Versão e **algumas configurações como Roles e Services**.

*Obs: Minha aplicação não é Web.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446390/how-to-detect-iis-version-using-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As informações sobre o seu IIS podem ser obtidas [usando o provedor ADSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524997%28v=vs.90%29). Os exemplos são do IIS 6, mas não haveria motivo para não funcionar em versões posteriores do IIS.

[Neste artigo há exemplos de como obter algumas informações e até mesmo criar sites no IIS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99634/Use-C-to-manage-IIS).

Além disso, ainda há [o excelente artigo que ensina como obter configurações do IIS pelo Active Directory](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).

[Este artigo também é um esforço mais direcionado para ler as configurações do IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114104757/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/11/24/accessing-iis-7-0-features-programmatically-from-configuration-file-s-c.aspx).

Comment: Upovte. Caso os artigos atendam a pergunta, irei marcar como resposta! Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Uma das maneiras provavelmente possíveis de fazer isso é através de consultas por [`WMI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28VS.80%29.aspx). Algumas informações podem ser vistas na página [**IIS WMI Provider**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Para trabalhar com o *IIS* e *WMI*, é necessário usar as classes do *namespace* [`MicrosoftIISv2`](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/microsoftiisv2/default.html). Há alguns exemplos [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525320(v=vs.90).aspx).

**Nota**: Se estiver usando o IIS 7, é necessário habilitar a [compatibilidade com o IIS 6 WMI](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkaddiis6wmicompatibilityroleservice.htm), para poder o [`MicrosoftIISv2`](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/microsoftiisv2/default.html) estar presente.

Nessa [**outra página**](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/iis/iis-6-0-getting-information-using-wmi/) mostra alguns exemplos de como obter informações usando [`WMI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146%28VS.80%29.aspx) (*testado no IIS 6 e Windows Server 2003*).

Acredito que também seja possível obter algumas informações com a classe [`Environment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Environment(v=vs.110).aspx). Segundo [esta página](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/how-to-get-server-iis-information-like.html), isso também pode ser feito usando o [`Request.ServerVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396(v=vs.90).aspx), exemplo:

```
lblServerIP.Text = Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
lblMachineName.Text = Environment.MachineName;
lblUserDomainName.Text = Environment.UserDomainName.ToString();
lblUserName.Text = Environment.UserName;
lblOSVersion.Text = Environment.OSVersion.ToString();
lblStartTime.Text = (Environment.TickCount / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + "Hours";
lblNowTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
lblIISVersion.Text = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];
lblIsHTTPS.Text = Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"];
lblPATHS.Text = Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"];
lblPATHS2.Text = Request.ServerVariables["PATH_TRANSLATED"];
lblPORT.Text = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
lblSessionID.Text = Session.SessionID;
```

Todas as variáveis podem ser vistas na página [**IIS Server Variables**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: eu n posso utilizar o "Request" pq minha aplicação n é web.

Comment: @psNytrancez Postei a resposta visando algo *genérico*, geralmente esse tipo de pergunta é para WEB. Em todo caso tem outro modo com `WMI`. Uma outra coisa que esqueci de colocar na resposta, é essa [**página da MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347649(v=vs.90).aspx). É sobre a seção de referência das APIs para trabalhar com o IIS **7**.

Comment: Essa API com o II7 também cai no mesmo cenário da aplicação não ser web.

Comment: @psNytrancez Acho que dá sim [trabalhar com isso em Desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3228813/1608936).